# JQuery Ajax call not getting the respose from the servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, jquery, response

Once the submit button is clicked, The name typed on the name textbox is printed in the servlet . But the response send by the servlet is not coming back to the client. I am not sure where i am going wrong. Need help.

JQuery-Ajax i am calling my sampleServlet.

**HTML PAGE**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".Submit").click(function(){
 nameVal=$("#name").val();
 alert(nameVal  ) ;
 $.get("http://localhost:8080/dummyService/SampleServlet", {name:nameVal}, function(data) {//This function is supposed to be called once the servlet send the response
 alert(data) ;
 $("#flag").html(data) ;
  });
 });
 });

</script>



<form id="sampleform" method="POST">
<center>
 Enter your Name:  <input id="name" class="name" type="text">  <br/><br/>
                   <input class="Submit" name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit"> 
</center>
</form>
<div id="flag"> </div>

**SampleServlet**

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  System.out.println("INSIDE DO GET");
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
  System.out.println(name);
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("Hello " + name);
  out.flush();
  out.close();
 }
```

Comment: try with `$.get("/dummyService/SampleServlet"`

Comment: also see in the firebug for erros

Comment: is the page calling the servlet also on port 8080, or maybe is on port 80 from apache, because that can be a problem.

Comment: @3nigma,@stivlo Actually the html page is not in the server code base. After placing the page inside the server and changing to $.get("/dummyService/SampleServlet") works fine. What difference it makes?

Comment: @james007 explained in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML page containing the JavaScript and your servlet must be on the same hostname and port because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).